# Ensuring C++ doubles are 64 bits

Tags: c++, types, precision, compiler-construction, ieee-754

In my C++ program, I need to pull a 64 bit float from an external byte sequence. Is there some way to ensure, at compile-time, that doubles are 64 bits? Is there some other type I should use to store the data instead?

Edit: If you're reading this and *actually* looking for a way to ensure storage in the IEEE 754 format, have a look at Adam Rosenfield's answer below.

Comment: Exactly what are you doing?  Are you looking for a completely portable way to take eight bytes and interpret them as an IEEE-standard 64-bit floating-point number?

Comment: @David: Yes, that's exactly what I'm doing. I'd found something somewhere that said C++ floats and doubles were in the IEEE-754 format. I wasn't sure whether doubles always used the same precision and wanted to add a check for it.

Comment: Now I'm not sure that my original information was correct. What's the convention here? Should I delete this question and add another asking about conversion from IEEE-754?

Comment: IIUC: 1) IEEE 754 is not guaranteed by the standard (otherwise, I fail to see the point for std::numeric_limits::is_iec559) 2) is_iec559 == true does not guarantee a binary representation.

Comment: Eric: numeric_limits::is_iec559 exists because numeric_limits is designed to be extensible, and, for example, there might be a numeric_limits<BigFloat> specialization for a user-defined BigFloat type for which is_iec559==false. However, you're right that built-in floats might not be IEEE 754.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An improvement on the other answers (which assume a char is 8-bits, the standard does not guarantee this..). Would be like this:

```
char a[sizeof(double) * CHAR_BIT == 64];
```

or

```
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(double) * CHAR_BIT == 64);
```

You can find CHAR_BIT defined in `<limits.h>` or `<climits>`.

Comment: um, no, it does not at all. sizeof returns in units of chars. CHAR_BIT is defined as the number of bits per char. multiply sizeof(x) by CHAR_BIT and you have *exactly* how many bits x is.

Comment: So for example, on x86 CHAR_BIT is defined as 8. sizeof(double) return's 8. (8 * 8) == 64.

Comment: Quoting the standard, 5.3.3p1: "The sizeof operator yields the number of bytes in the object representation of its operands." QED

Comment: Also, since CHAR_BIT is inhertied from c, the rules of c apply: to quote the C99 draft standard (section 6.2.6.1p3): "Values stored in objects of any other object type consist of n x CHAR_BIT bits, where n is the size of an object of that type, in bytes."

Comment: Finally, from that SAME paragraph you quoted: "sizeof(char), sizeof(signed char) and sizeof(unsigned char) are 1;" if sizeof(char) == 1 and sizeof by definition returns in units of bytes. then that means that a char *is* the same size as a byte. However, a byte need not be 8-bits.

Comment: So yes, your original comment was correct that I assumed that a char is the same size as a byte. But you are incorrect in thinking they are different. The standard clearly shows that they are the same. However, it makes no claims that a byte is 8-bits.

Answer (score 40):

In C99, you can just check if the preprocessor symbol `__STDC_IEC_559__` is defined.  If it is, then you are guaranteed that a `double` will be an 8-byte value represented with IEEE 754 (also known as IEC 60559) format.  See the C99 standard, Annex F.  I'm not sure if this symbol is available in C++, though.

```
#ifndef __STDC_IEC_559__
#error "Requires IEEE 754 floating point!"
#endif
```

Alternatively, you can check the predefined constants `__DBL_DIG__` (should be 15), `__DBL_MANT_DIG__` (should be 53), `__DBL_MAX_10_EXP__` (should be 308), `__DBL_MAX_EXP__` (should be 1024), `__DBL_MIN_10_EXP__` (should be -307), and `__DBL_MIN_EXP__` (should be -1021).  These should be available in all flavors of C and C++.

Comment: This is an even better solution than I'd hoped for. Accepted Evan's answer, though, since it answers the question as it exists. I just asked the wrong question.

Comment: This is inconsistent between compilers and platforms.

Answer (score 14):

Check `std::numeric_limits< double >::is_iec559` if you need to know whether your C++ implementation supports standard doubles. This guarantees not only that the total number of bits is 64, but also the size and position of all fields inside the double.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you should focus on the "raw size" of your double (which is generally 80 bit, not 64 bit), but rather on its precision.

Thanks to numeric_limits::digits10 this is fairly easy.

Comment: 80 bit doubles are an Intel-ism, and true only if the FPU is actually in 80-bit mode (there's also 64-bit mode)...

Comment: And even 32-bit mode depending on how you initialize Direct3D.

Answer (score 5):

The solution without boost is to define the array like so

```
char a[ 8 == sizeof(double) ];
```

If the double is not 64 bits then the code will looks like

```
char a[0];
```

which is an compile time error. Just put the appropriate comment near this instruction.

Comment: a byte isn't guaranteed to be 8-bits

Comment: @Evan: Interesting point. Add "&& (unsigned char) 255 == 255 && (unsigned char) 256 == 0" to the condition to check that chars are 8 bits.

Comment: What about the case when the size of the double is 16 byte, but the byte consist of 4 bits?

Comment: @j_random_hacker: better yet add "&& CHAR_BIT == 8" since CHAR_BIT is defined as the number of bits per char/unsigned char.

Comment: or better yet "sizeof(double) * CHAR_BIT == 64"

Comment: Mykola, a byte can never consist of 4 bits. it has to have at least 8 bits.

Comment: ok. I put this only as example to the j_random_hacker proposal

Comment: @Evan: I agree, "sizeof(double) * CHAR_BIT == 64" is a better solution (e.g. it handles Mykola's quirky 16 * 4 case) as well as being clearer.

Comment: Actually, char a[0]; compiles fine on gcc. Try something like char a[1-!STATEMENT] instead. If statement holds, it declares a to be of zero size. Else, it declares a of negative size which is illegal.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Boost static assertions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html) to do this. Look at the [Use at namespace scope](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html#boost_staticassert.namespace) example.

Answer (score 1):

See [this post](http://bytes.com/groups/c/220022-if-sizeof) for a similar problem and a non-boost compile time assertion called CCASSERT.

Answer (score 0):

For compilers supporting C11 or C++11, I use something similar to @EvanTeran's:

```
#include <assert.h> // defines macro static_assert in C11 

static_assert(sizeof(double) * CHAR_BIT == 64, "64-bit double is assumed.");
```

In C++11 or later, `static_assert` is a keyword.