# Looking for datatypes of similar precision in multiple programming languages e.g. C/C++, D, Go

Tags: c++, c, go, d, floating-accuracy

I am trying to implement a program with floating point numbers, using two or more programming languages. The program does say 50k iterations to finally bring the error to very small value.

To ensure that my results are comparable, I wanted to make sure I use data types of same precision in different languages. Would you please tell if there is correspondence between float/double of C/C++ to that in D and Go. I expect C/C++ and D to be quite close in this regard, but not sure. Thanks a lot.

Comment: C and C++ are more closer than C and D

Comment: Yes, that was implicit in my question. I have modified it accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, for compiled languages, floating point format and precision comes down to two things:

1. The library used to implement the floating point functions that aren't directly supported in hardware.
2. The hardware the system is running on.

It may also depend on what compiler options you give (and how sophisticated the compiler is in general) - many modern processors have vector instructions, and the result may be subtly different than if you use "regular" floating point instructions (e.g. FPU vs. SSE on x86 processors). You may also see differences, sometimes, because the internal calculations on an x86 FPU is 80-bits, stored as 64-bits when the computation is completed.

But generally, given the same hardware, and similar type of compilers, I'd expect to get the same result [and roughly the same performance] from two different [sufficiently similar] languages.

Most languages have either only "double" (typically 64-bit) or "single and double" (e.g. float - typically 32-bit and double - typically 64-bit in C/C++ - and probably D as well, but I'm not that into D).

Comment: I think, Go does not have "double", but only float32 and float64. So that is why I was wondering about Go (http://golang.org/pkg/math/). Both C/C++ and D have double.

Comment: For D: `float`=IEEE 32 bit FP, `double`=64 bit, `real`=most precise IEEE FP type with hardware support.

Answer (score 2):

In Go, floating point types follow the IEEE-754 standard.

Straight from the spec (http://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types)

```
float32     the set of all IEEE-754 32-bit floating-point numbers
float64     the set of all IEEE-754 64-bit floating-point numbers
```

I'm not familiar with D, but this page might be of interest: http://dlang.org/float.html.

For C/C++, the standard doesn't require IEEE-754, but in C++ you could use `is_iec559()` to check if your compiler is using IEEE-754.  See this question: [How to check if C++ compiler uses IEEE 754 floating point standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777484/how-to-check-if-c-compiler-uses-ieee-754-floating-point-standard)