# Why are the programming languages limits precision of 22/7 equally?

Tags: python, ruby, haskell, floating-point, erlang

I tried

```
Erlang
$ erl
1> Pi = 22/7.
3.142857142857143

Haskell
$ ghci 
Prelude> 22/7
3.142857142857143

Python
$ python
>>> 22/7.0
3.142857142857143

Ruby 
$ irb
2.1.6 :001 > 22 / 7.0
 => 3.142857142857143
```

The results are the same. Why?

Comment: Why would you expect differences? They're all implementing [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) on the same hardware.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You should very probably post that as an answer !

Comment: Nice, i didn't know that. Please post it.

Comment: Why is this labelled "pi"?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14631761/3001761

Comment: @steenslag i didn't know how to ask in general, but question is clear.

Comment: 22/7 isn't pi though, it's wrong after the 2nd decimal place

Comment: Yes, please don't use 22/7 for pi. In Haskell, just write `pi`, which gives `3.141592653589793`.

Comment: Agreed. Most languages have a constant defined already. In Ruby, it is `Math::PI`.

Comment: use 355/113, if you must. it's good for 6 places.

Comment: @WillNess, there are some great approximations from Ramanujen and such that will go much further pretty quickly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This happens because all the languages are using the same numerical representation for non-integer numbers: [IEEE 754 floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) with, most likely, the same level of precision. (Either 32-bit "floats" or 64-bit "doubles", depending on how your system and languages are configured.)

Floating point numbers are the default choice for this sort of operation, in large part because they're supported directly in hardware. However, fundamentally, nothing stops languages from supporting other kinds of numbers as well. This is easiest to demonstrate in Haskell, which has rational numbers in its standard library:

```
λ> 22/7 :: Rational
22 % 7
```

A rational number is a fraction, so it's stored as a pair of integers and you don't lose any precision when dividing. At the same time, some operations are more difficult and less efficient than with normal floating point numbers.

Another possible representation are [fixed-point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) which have a smaller range than floating point numbers but do a better job of maintaining precision *within* that range. (I'm really handwaving a lot of details here.) You can try these out in Haskell too:

```
λ> import Data.Fixed
λ> 22/7 :: Deci
3.1
λ> 22/7 :: Centi
3.14
λ> 22/7 :: Micro
3.142857
```

Comment: Not only because they share the same representation which is exactly 3.142857142857142793701541449991054832935333251953125, but also because they share the same way of printing the shortest decimal representation that would be correctly rounded to the same floating point.