# Rounding issue while conver float to unsigned short

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I am getting wrong value while converting float to unsigned integer

```
TMAC_PAYLOAD_SCALE = 0.10
Data = (unsigned short)(mData / TMAC_PAYLOAD_SCALE);
189.20/0.10 = 1891  (I am expecting 1892)
184.59/0.10 = 1845  (I am expecting 1846)
```

Tried with both round and ceil function but still getting wrong answer

Comment: `round` should give the correct result - are you sure you used it correctly ?

Comment: [Looks fine to me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73b541ddbfdab551) (I used round for the first, but you need it for the second too). The need for round in the first case is only due to the joys of floating-point computations : 10.0*189.20 gives you the right answer. In the second case, it is due to the fact that a cast truncates the data in some way, so 1845.9 becomes 1845.

Comment: @PaulR In case of VC yes. But generally speaking, the type `double` (returned by `round`) is not guaranteed to be IEEE 754 and to allow _exact_ representation for all integers. So we may have cases when after truncating the result is less than expected. (I tried to illustrate it with `float` in my answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If C++ compiler [uses IEEE 754](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5777484) you can try [round](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/round/) function:

```
Data = (unsigned short)round(mData / TMAC_PAYLOAD_SCALE);
```

However, assuming that the result of division is non-negative, the following approach is perhaps better:

```
Data = (unsigned short)(mData / TMAC_PAYLOAD_SCALE + 0.5);
```

The reason is that for floating-integral conversion the fractional part is just discarded. So if the rounding function cannot represent the exact integral value `N`, and returns a value "slightly less" than `N`, then after casting we get `N-1`.

This problem can be illustrated by the following (IEEE 754 compatible) code:

```
int a = 16777217;
float f = a; // not double
int b = f;
cout << a << " " << b << endl;
```

which outputs

```
16777217 16777216
```

While the described problem should not happen in case of IEEE 754 and `round` function (since `round` returns `double` which allows exact representation for integers), still the first approach does not look very convenient because we have to keep all these assumptions in mind.

Comment: I did like this   Data = round(mData) * 100) / 100;

Comment: @Sijith You need to round the result of the '/'-operation, not one argument. (The brackets are unbalanced BTW.)

Comment: @Sijith I updates the answer, you may look at the second option as well.

Answer (score 0):

what i have tried-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main ()
{

        printf("%hd\n",(unsigned short)ceil(189.20/0.10)); // you can use ceilf also
        printf("%hd\n",(unsigned short)floor(184.59/0.10));

        return 0;
}
```

output-

```
root@sathish1:~/My Docs/Programs# ./a.out 
1892
1845
```