# Negate operator vs boost::math::changesign on a floating point value

Tags: c++, boost, floating-point

I have discovered [boost::math::changesign](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/sign_functions.html) function, but cannot find a rationale of using it. The Internet keeps radio silence and even Boost itself barely uses it.

My thoughts were:

1. There are some values where `-x` is forbidden.
2. To avoid compiler bugs.
3. Faster at runtime.

However:

1. It seems to be a valid operation on any value, [at least for IEEE 754](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800311/is-it-always-safe-to-negate-a-floating-point-number).
2. The different compilers/platforms I have tried generate bit-identical results for `changesign` and `-x` https://godbolt.org/g/4ttsfW.
3. Current GCC and Clang produces the same machine codes for both methods, the older ones (and any MSVC) generate a way longer assembly for `changesign` https://godbolt.org/g/nT6j26.

Comment: From the link: _"For finite values, this function has the same effect as simple negation, the assignment z = -z, but for nonfinite values, infinities and NaNs, the changesign(x) function may be the only portable way to ensure that the sign bit is changed."_

Comment: That statement has no citations and says "may be", so it "may be" wrong.

Comment: It says “may be” because C++ allows implementations to have somewhat different behaviors regarding special values. In one implementation `-x` might always work if `x` is a NaN. In such an implementation, `changesign` is not the only way to ensure the sign bit is changed. In another implementation, `-x` might trap if `x` is a NaN (or a certain NaN). In such an implementation, `changesign` is the only way to ensure the sign bit is changed. So “may be” is qualifying different behaviors of C++ implementations, not telling you `changesign` might or might not have this rationale for its existence.

Comment: @NikitaKniazev I posted that quote because I think you should have included that information in the question, given that it was written by the package maintainers.  It would have made the question clearer.

Answer (score 1):

`boost::math::changesign` effectively works on its operand a bit level: It changes the sign bit and is not affected by other aspects of the operand. This differs from the unary `-` operator because the unary `-` operator is mathematical and may be affected by values that are NaNs (for example, it may trap if the input is a NaN). Whether the `-` operator is affected by such things is implementation-dependent, whereas `boost::math::changesign` is intended to change the sign regardless of the C++ implementation.

1. Is irrelevant because the C++ unary `-` operator is not bound to the `negate` operation in IEEE 754-2008. In other words, C++ says it has a unary `-` operator and describes some of its behavior, and IEEE 754 has a `negate` operation that reverses the sign bit, but the C++ standard does not require that the unary `-` operator perform the IEEE 754 `negate` operation. Additionally, [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800311/is-it-always-safe-to-negate-a-floating-point-number) in the question goes to a question that is answered with caveats that confirm C++’s unary `-` might not function as the IEEE 754 `negate`.
2. and 3. show a set of points in the set of possible implementations of C++ (or set of possible approximate implementations of C++) and do not speak to the existence or non-existence of other implementations of C++ that behave differently.