# How do I convert the decimal part in a string that holds a double value into a double in C?

Tags: c

I need to convert a string that is a positive valid double (ex: 52.503) into a double without the use of library functions including math.h and string.h. What I'm having most difficulty is in getting the values after the decimal point. If I had pow I would use a for loop and raise 10 to the power of i (i starting at 1 from the 1st value after the decimal point) and use that so I can get the right amount of decimal places. How would I do it without pow?

edit:nvm i solved it

```
#include <stdio.h>
double convert_to_double(const char *digits);
int main (void) {
char s[10] = "5009.48";
double a = convert_to_double(s);
printf("a is %lf",a);
}

double convert_to_double(const char *digits) { 
    double sum1 = 0;
    double sum2 = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int c = 0;

    while( digits[i] != '.' ) {
        c++;
        i++;
    }

    for (i=0 ; i<c; i++) {  //Records values before decimal into sum1
    sum1 = 10 * sum1 + (digits[i] - '0') ;
    }
    i = c+1;

    while (digits[i] != '\0')  //Records values after decimal point into sum2
    {   
        sum2 = sum2 + (double)(digits[i] - '0')/10; //Input: 5009.48 Output: 0.4+0.8=1.4
        i++;                                              
    }


 return  sum1+sum2;

}
```

Comment: [`strtod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof)

Comment: *"Without the use of library functions."* Convert to an integer in the usual char-by-char method you are using, to `long long`. Remember the position of the decimal point but otherwise ignore it. Then assign to `double` and divide by `10` as many times as the position of the decimal point (from the end) shows.

Comment: thanks @WeatherVane ! Worked for me

Comment: @weathervane I'm wondering if using directly a double for the char-by-char method would introduct an error at every x*10 and/or x/10. (Forgive me, it is late)

Comment: If you're feeling adventurous could try banging out the bits into a `long int` and recasting to `float` if you can nail the [correct floating point format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777484/how-to-check-if-c-compiler-uses-ieee-754-floating-point-standard).

Comment: @RobertoCaboni the `long long` I mentioned to use can hold more siginificant digits than `double` so switch to `double` as late as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Changed it to this after trying out @weathervane's suggestion

```
double convert_to_double(const char *digits) { 
    double sum1 = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int d = 0;

    while( digits[i] != '.' ) { //Records which index decimal point is located.
        c++;
        i++;
    }

    for (i=0 ; digits[i] != '\0' ; i++) { //Records double value including decimal part as integer.
    if (digits[i] == '.' ) i++;
    sum1 = 10 * sum1 + (digits[i] - '0') ;
    }

    i = c+1;

    while (digits[i] != '\0') { //Records how many values are after decimal point
        d++;
        i++;
    }
    while (d>0) { //Shifts the decimal point by one place to the left d times. 
        sum1 = sum1/10;
        d--;
    }
 return sum1;
}
```

Comment: I suggested building the integer in `long long` but for fewer than 54 significant bits it won't matter.