# Is the result of sqrtf exact when value is actually squared?

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision, sqrt

I wanted to know if the result of [`std::sqrtf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt) is exact if the value is actually squared.

```
int value = ...;
int root = (int)sqrtf((float)value); // is this safe?
```

Note that `value` is integer and not always squared. in that case I want to truncate the result.

Comment: Note that `root * root` might not be exactly representable as a `float`.

Comment: I just updated my question, sorry, I think it's important that value is int casted to float

Comment: With your updated question, the answer depends on the target architecture's implementation of `float`.  You might be asking about the behavior of [IEEE 754 floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777484/how-to-check-if-c-compiler-uses-ieee-754-floating-point-standard).

Comment: It's not guaranteed. An integer could have a square root whose exact value is just fractionally less than an integer (and not representable as a float). The sqrt routine could then correctly round that value up to that integer, thus defeating your requirement to truncate. Whether such a thing happens in practise I don't know.

Comment: `(int) sqrtf((float) 2147395599)` gives the wrong answer because `2147395599` rounds to the wrong float

Comment: Re: `// is this safe?` -- define "safe".

Comment: Short answer: no.   The only way for the result to be exact is if a `float` can represent all possible values of `root*root`.   A `float` is typically a 32-bit representation, and `int` is *often* a 32-bit representation.   Which (in that case) means an `int` can represent values that a `float` cannnot (and vice versa).   If you want to compute the "integer square root" exactly (in the sense of "value of `root` such that `root*root <= value`) don't use floating point at all - there are (relatively simple) algorithms available if you search for that term.

Comment: @M.kazem Akhgary, `long root = lround(sqrt((double)value));` will get you closer - albeit not a _truncate_.  Have you considered `(int)sqrt((double)value);`?  (that will _usually_ work.)  What is your higher level goal?