# convert from float-point to custom numeric type

Tags: c++, floating-point, type-conversion

I've created my own fixed-type integer types and the library works fine with many compilers and platforms, the only problem left to solve is to convert from built-in float-point types to my types.

The float-point types may have small mantissa but along with exponent it may have big value so if i choose to cast `float`, `double`, or `long double` say to `long long` or `unsigned long long` a truncation may occur.

If the compiler use IEEE-754 specification it'll be easy to extract mantissa and exponent, but what if the compiler use some other format.

So, my question: is there any generic algorithm that allows me to extract the full value from a float-point using only the language features?

thanks

Comment: You could get a good insight about the characteristics of the FP types on the current platform by using the `std::numeric_limits<T>` members; from that you can determine the radix and the size of the mantissa, thus determining by what you have to multiply the number to get the whole mantissa out when casting to an integer (also, you get to know if is there available any integer big enough for this to work).

Comment: CHeck out the [`frexp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/frexp) family of functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may find useful [my answer to a somewhat similar question  here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14955046/968261). The idea is that if the underlying format is binary, you are pretty much guaranteed to be able to extract the  mantissa and exponent without loss if there are no more bits in the mantissa than there are in the biggest integer type. You can use `double frexp(double value, int *exp);` and `double ldexp(double x, int exp);` for the purpose.

Another option would be to `sprintf()` the number using `%a` to get all the digits and then manually convert the textual representation into what you need.