# conversion from double to unsigned long long failed

Tags: c++, floating-point, type-conversion

Based on the question [convert from float-point to custom numeric type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057546/convert-from-float-point-to-custom-numeric-type), I figured out a portable safe way to convert float-point type into array of integers and the code works fine, but for some values when converting from `double` to `unsigned long long` **with precision that can be safely represented by `unsigned long long`** the conversion fails not by compile-time error but with invalid value which is minimum representable value for `signed long long` or zero, the conversion fails on visual c++ 2008, intel xe 2013 and gcc 4.7.2.

here is the code: (notice first statement inside `while` loop in `main` function)

```
#ifndef CHAR_BIT
#include <limits.h>
#endif

#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef signed int          int32;
typedef signed long long    int64;
typedef unsigned int       uint32;
typedef unsigned long long uint64;

typedef float  float32;
typedef double float64;

// get size of type in bits corresponding to CHAR_BIT.
template<typename t>
struct sizeof_ex
{
    static const uint32 value = sizeof(t) * CHAR_BIT;
};

// factorial function
float64 fct(int32 i)
{
    float64 r = 1;
    do r *= i; while(--i > 1);
    return r;
}

int main()
{
    // maximum 2 to power that can be stored in uint32
    const uint32 power_2  = uint32(~0);
    // number of binary digits in power_2
    const uint32 digit_cnt = sizeof_ex<uint32>::value;
    // number of array elements that will store expanded value
    const uint32 comp_count = DBL_MAX_EXP / digit_cnt + uint32((DBL_MAX_EXP / digit_cnt) * digit_cnt < DBL_MAX_EXP);
    // array elements
    uint32 value[comp_count];

    // get factorial for 23
    float64 f = fct<float64>(23);
    // save sign for later correction
    bool sign = f < 0;
    // remove sign from float-point if exists
    if (sign) f *= -1;

    // get number of binary digits in f
    uint32 actual_digits = 0;
    frexp(f, (int32*)&actual_digits);

    // get start index in array for little-endian format
    uint32 start_index = (actual_digits / digit_cnt) + uint32((actual_digits / digit_cnt) * digit_cnt < actual_digits) - 1;

    // get all parts but the last
    while (start_index > 0)
    {
        // store current part
        // in this line the compiler fails
        value[start_index] = uint64(f / power_2);
        // exclude it from f
        f -= power_2 * float64(value[start_index]);
        // decrement index
        --start_index;
    }
    // get last part
    value[0] = uint32(f);
}
```

The convert code above will give different result from compiler to another, meaning when the parameter of factorial function say 20 all compilers return valid result, when the value greater than 20 some compiler gets part of the result others don't and when it is get bigger e.g. `35` it become zero.

please tell me why those error occurs?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your conversion logic makes any sense.

You have a value called "power_2" which is not actually a power of 2, despite commenting that it is.

You extract bits of a very large (>64-bit) number by dividing by something less than 32-bits. Obviously the result of that will be >32 bits, but you store it into a 32-bit value, truncating it. Then you remultiply that by the original divisor and subtract from your float. However as the number was truncated, you are subtracting much less than the original value, which almost certainly wasn't what you expected.

I think there's more wrong that just that - you don't really always want the top 32 bits, for a number which is not a multiple of 32-bits long, you want the actual length mod 32.

Here's a somewhat lazy hack on your code that does what I *think* you're trying to do. Note that the `pow()` could be optimised out.

```
while (start_index > 0)
{
    float64 fpow = pow(2., 32. * start_index);
    // store current part
    // in this line the compiler fails

    value[start_index] = f / fpow;
    // exclude it from f

    f -= fpow * float64(value[start_index]);
    // decrement index
    --start_index;
}
```

That's pretty much untested, but hopefully illustrates what I mean.

Comment: I've changed the code many until i forgot to update the comments to mean what i want, thank you very much for your help.