# Calculate epsilon for a float in C

Tags: c, bit

I have to use bit/integer ops to figure out the epsilon for a given value in C. I know in terms of bit patterns that computing the next neighbor involves incrementing the mantissa, and if that overflows, to increment the exponent - but I'm not sure where to begin in terms of calculating the epsilon.

**I can't use floating point math - so I need to generate the bit pattern directly. This makes it trickier because I cannot subtract.**

**Here's my understanding (based on some research I've done here on SO):** the range changes obviously as the numbers get bigger, but I'm not sure how to use `FLT_EPSILON` to generate the right numbers. For 2^2x numbers, perhaps it is `(FLT_EPSILON - 1) * number`?

Comment: Your first paragraph is on the right way. However, forget about `FLT_EPSILON` : that's specifically the positive epsilon of `1.0f`. Edit : [here's a track](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15685301/3233393)

Comment: Check the edit, should've made this clear.

Comment: Wait, so you have to reimplement floating-point subtraction by hand ?

Comment: I am supposed to generate the epsilon using only bit operators and I should be able to do this by hand. I'm just very confused as to where to start.

Comment: Why can't you use floating-point math? Is this homework?

Comment: What does "2^2x numbers" mean? Do you mean powers of two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your epsilon is simply the value of one LSB increment to the mantissa, the value should be 2^(exp-23).  So if your input is `[s][exp][mantissa]` your epsilon should be `[0][exp-23][0]`.  Sure enough, when given an input of 1.0 (`[0][127][0]`), the result is `[0][104][0]` = 2^-23 = `FLT_EPSILON`.

Comment: You beat me to it. Have a +1.

Comment: It's one LSB increment to the mantissa, and in cases of overflow, and increment to the exponent as well. Does this property still hold?

Comment: @marchon It's a bit tricky at the overflow boundary, but that's because the definition of the epsilon kind of breaks down there, too.  Depending on the formal definition you're going with, it may need to be tweaked.  As an example, 1.0 is 2^-23 away from 1.0+eps, but it is only 2^-24 away from 1.0-eps.  In that case, which is the right answer?  The algorithm above will give the larger of the two, but you could easily add a check in that would give you the smaller value.

Comment: Probably best to calculate both and go with the smaller. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, have worked on it for a while - and I can't see what the check would be to return the smaller of the two. I can increase the exponent: if (mantissa + 1 >= (1 << 23)) exponent++; but how would I do this check and adjust accordingly?

Answer (score 2):

due to IEEE 754 format you need 1 in mantissa and 127 shifted to 23

```
float x;

*((int*) &x) = 1;
*((int*) &x) = *((int*) &x) | 104 << 23;

printf("%.12f\n", FLT_EPSILON);
printf("%.12f\n", x);
```