# C: Calculated machine epsilon differs from limits.h

Tags: c, epsilon

I tried to use the following program to estimate the machine epsilon with a simple C program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <float.h>

int main(){
  float f = 1.0f;
  float prev_f = 1.0f;

  while( 1 + f != 1 ){ 
    prev_f = f;
    f /= 2;  
  }
  prev_f *= 2;  

  printf("Calculated epsilon for float is %.10g", prev_f);
  printf("The actual value is %.10f", FLT_EPSILON);
  return 0;
}
```

where my output is

```
Calculated epsilon for float is 2.802596929e-45

The actual value is 0.0000001192
```

Can anyone explain this deviation to me? Is it architecture specific? Compiler dependent? Am i doing something wrong?

**EDIT:**
The problem seemed to be due to me using the -Ofast optimization in gcc. Using -O instead solves the problem.

Comment: You've calculated the _precision_ of `float` (24 bits ~= 7.2 decimal digits), rather than epsilon.

Comment: I get the same value for both if I take out the `prev_f *= 2;` line which shouldn't be there. But in your output I don't know how you get the first output - maybe some compiler setting like `-ffast-math` which causes inaccurate results..

Comment: That's odd - I get `2.384185791e-07` which is the actual value * 2. What compiler are you using? What architecture are you on? What compiler options are you using?

Comment: Example of correct results calculated: https://godbolt.org/z/Ghf1TP

Comment: And here is an alternative method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24915880/6865932

Comment: Won't `float` values be upcast to `double` before the arithmetic takes place?  Instead of comparing directly to `1 + f` you should assign it to another `float` and compare to that.

Comment: @MarkRansom: No, the *usual arithmetic conversions* convert an `int` and `float` to `float` and `float`. However, C implementations are nonetheless permitted to evaluate the expression with greater precision than its nominal type, `float`.

Comment: The problem seemed to be caused by the optimization i was using, -Ofast, as suggested by @interjay. The output is now identical to that of FLT_EPSILON from limits.h, using the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remove `prev_f *= 2;`. Since the loop remembers the value of `f` for which `1 + f != 1` failed by storing it in `prev_f`, the value of `prev_f` when the loop ends is the last value that caused `1+f` not to equal 1, which is the result you want.<sup>1</sup>

Second, C implementations are allowed to evaluate floating-point expressions with more precision than their nominal types. It appears your C implementation is effectively evaluating `1+f != 1` with infinite precision (which is possible by recognizing at compile time that `1+f != 1` evaluated to infinite precision is true iff `f != 0`, so optimization can change it to `f != 0`). Thus, the loop terminates only when `f` becomes zero, at which point the previous `f` was the smallest possible representable positive value, which, for the format commonly used for `float` is 2<sup>−149</sup>. (And your current code doubles this and prints 2<sup>−148</sup>.) Note that the (effective) infinite precision occurs only in evaluating `1 + f != 1`, not in the assignment `f /= 2;`. This is because the C standard requires implementations to “discard” excess precision when casts and assignments are performed. This gives us the solution to this problem: Change `1 + f != 1` to `(float) (1 + f) != 1`. This will force the evaluation to be done as if in the `float` format.<sup>2</sup>

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Sort of. The machine episilon is sometimes incorrectly stated to be the smallest value *x* such that evaluating 1+*x* produces a value greater than *x*. However, it is defined to be the different between 1 and the next greater representable value, say 1+. If we let *x* be slightly greater than ½ (such as ½(1+)), then eavluating 1+*x* would produce 1+ due to rounding, even though *x* is less than the machine epsilon. However, this code will find the correct value provided the issues described above are fixed and the floating-point radix is two, since it never tests one of these false candidates for the machine epsilon and therefore never finds one.

<sup>2</sup> Generally, double-rounding problems can occur: When the C implementation uses excess precision to evaluate an expression, it may round the ideal mathematical result to that excess precision. When it is forced to “discard” the excess precision by a cast or assignment, it rounds to the nominal precision. It is possible for these two roundings to cause a different result than if there were only one rounding to the nominal precision. However, that will not be a problem in this particular case.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I have a few questions and comments. First and foremost, the problem seemed to be due to using the gcc optimization option -Ofast. I don't quite understand why. Disabling this, and using the above code i get a value that is exactly identical to the contained in FLT_EPSILON from limits.h. However, as you wrote, prev_f *= 2 doesn't seem to do anything. Removing it results in the same value in the end, which is kind of confusing to me. Do you know why this is?