# cpp: how to compute epsMachine in -Ofast

Tags: c++, rounding, ieee-754, compiler-flags

How do I compute the *correct* value for the machine round-off unit of a given typename in presence of arbitrary compiler optimization flags? If impossible, let's restrict the set of possible compiler flags to all optimization flags set by `-Ofast`.

##### Background

The following code

```cpp
template<typename Tfloat>
Tfloat get_eps_mach(){
    Tfloat x=1, q=0.5, u=q;
    while( x!=(x+q*u) ){ u*=q; }
    return u;
}
```

will return ridiculously small numbers for the machine round-off unit `u` when the compiler option `-Ofast` is used. I understand why (it is due to `-ffast-math`, which grants the compiler permission to manipulate the comparison and incrementation), but I seek a way so that I can compute `u` for arbitrary numbers correctly. Notice: There is no personal flavor in what the term *correct* means here, because the value `u` is formally well-defined from the bit representation of the number type (mantissa length in particular).

While in my programming model that bit representation shall be black-box and inattainable and I do even not want to assume that the number type uses a mantissa or whatever, I still insist to hold an agnostic function that will return the correct value of `u`. (Hence it would also be a pointless "solution" to propose overloading the function for every common number type. Reason for my interest are:

1. that subsequent parameters (e.g., optimal truncations, optimal perturbations, reasonable tolerances, etc) will be computed as formulas of `u`.
2. that I do not want to worry that any future or user-defined number types will be needed at any point in the future, for which then the `get_eps_mach` function may not return the correct value, regardless what compiler options are used whatsoever.

Comment: Is the numeric_limits epsilon not usable with -Ofast?

Comment: Thanks @KIV. is it like a constexpr static function namespace, so that it computes epsMach for the respective typename? Because I thought it was a lookup table for each presently known number type, in which case it pertains the risk that a future number type may yield an incorrect result.

Comment: Those values are well known - well specified, so it doesn't make sense to compute it in runtime. You can just try to print values for the float and double and compare it with your template and how does it change with different compile options.

Comment: @KIV: what you refer to can be fixed with meta-programming. That does not relate to the following mindgame: Suppose I give you an object file and a header of number type FPfancy. Now you shall tell me what the correct value of u for FPfancy is. That is the question as asked. Now I assume you cannot, hence you cannot answer the question stated. Hence you are unhelpful. Rectify if I am misled.

Comment: When you are unsure, test it. Print the actual values or something (you can print it as hex to avoid rounding errors). Btw: it wasn't supposed to be answer, it was question if this can't be used instead.

Comment: @KIV: Sorry for my tone before. It was not meant as discredit. I acknowledge the effort to read and comment on questions. The issue is: The numerical limits seem to be only defined for the common std types. Now there are experiments with hexafloat (instead of quadfloat) where consumers define numbertypes constructed from std number types. And that is what I would like to be able to compute u for. At the moment, the issue already arises with -Ofast on the first level, i.e. when the typename is from std. But if we go deeper like hexafloat, the Ofast effects are within the operator definitions

Comment: that is why the use of numeric_limits will not solve the problem to me ultimately.

Comment: Why don't you simply *avoid* using `-Ofast`/`-ffast-math`? They are dangerous options that are explicitly documented to break some rules of C++ that can in some cases lead to incorrect results. Personally I would never use them since I prefer to be able to trust that if my code follows the rules I will get the expected results.

Comment: @JesperJuhl because it is fast, as hinted in the name ;)

Comment: I've yet to find a situation where the speed difference *actually* matters. But you do whatever you like.

Comment: Test changing `x!=(x+q*u)` to ` x != static_cast<Tfloat>(x + q*u)`, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66232786/c-calculated-machine-epsilon-differs-from-limits-h/66233520#66233520). The C++ standard allows implementations to evaluate floating-point expressions using more precision than the nominal type. When a cast is used, the implementation is required to use the nominal type.

Comment: Also, edit the question to provide a [mre], including a complete program that demonstrates the problem (important because optimization can change with small details, so having a complete exact program to reproduce is appropriate), the output you observe, the specific compiler version you use, and the command line you use to compile.

Comment: `-ffast-math` doesn't do anything you can't do yourself. Anecdotally, as the lead developer of an extremely popular high-performance software package, we never use `-ffast-math` (or its equivalent on other compilers). If you actually care about numeric computation enough to worry about its performance, worry about its correctness first. You'll never get that with `-ffast-math`.