# get the float number's exponents

Tags: c, floating-point, precision

I just started learning floating point and get to know the SME stuff. I'm still very confused about the mantissa... Can somebody explain to me how can I get the exp part of the float. I am sorry if that's a super stupid and basic question but I am having a hard time understanding it...

Also how do I implement the following function... clearly my implementation is wrong. But how do I do it?

```
// Extract the 8-bit exponent field of single precision
// floating point number f and return it as an unsigned byte
unsigned char get_exponent_field(float f)
{
// TODO: Your code here.
int bias = 127;
int expp = (int)f;
unsigned char E = expp-bias;

return E;
}
```

Comment: Did you search? Any of the "Related" links (right hand side) help? Such as [How to get the sign, mantissa and exponent of a floating point number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685181/how-to-get-the-sign-mantissa-and-exponent-of-a-floating-point-number).

Comment: The exponent bits in the a `float` are bit 1 to 8 (0-th bit is for sign), Use bit-shift and bit mask to get it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract the *IEEE-754 single precision exponent* from a `float` value (in *excess 127 notation*), you can use the float functions, or you can use a simple union with a *shift* and *mask* to do the same:

```
unsigned float_getexp (float f)
{
    union {
        unsigned u;
        float f;
    } uf;
    uf.f = f;
    return (uf.u >> 23) & 0xff;
}
```

If you want the actual exponent *bias* (i.e. the number of places the mantissa decimal is shifted during normalization prior to *hidden bit* removal), just subtract `127` from the value returned, or if you want that value returned, subtract it before the return.

Give it a try and let me know if you have questions. (**note:** the `type` should be `unsigned` for your exponent, instead of the `int` you have).

Comment: Hi can you explain how does this uf.u get value assigned and what does the & 0xff means?

Comment: Sure. All you are looking at is a function `float_getexp`. Inside the function the first variable is a `union` named `uf` (with an `unsigned` and `float` -- both 32-bits on most x86 hardware). Immediately after the `union` named `uf` is declared, the union is assigned the value (passed as a parameter to the function) in `uf.f = f;` (that's standard *dot operator* `struct/union` member referencing, e.g. `uf.f` references the float member of the union). Then the `unsigned` member `uf.u` is right-shifted 23 bits and the 2-bytes that represent the exponent are returned.

Answer (score 0):

First, get your floating-point number and calculate its binary form by converting both the integral and fractional parts separately.  Once you've got that, say you've got 11010.101(base-2).  **Normalize** the binary string: 1.1010101 x 2^4. Next, add your excess value, say excess 15, to the exponent of the sci. not. value, which would give you 19(base-ten).  Convert this to base-two; this will be your exponent.

This is just the structure of the operation, plug in your own bias, etc.