# Sign, mantissa, and exponent of a double

Tags: c, floating-point

I found the following code from [How to get the sign, mantissa and exponent of a floating point number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685181/how-to-get-the-sign-mantissa-and-exponent-of-a-floating-point-number)

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef union {
  float f;
  struct {
    unsigned int mantisa : 23;
    unsigned int exponent : 8;
    unsigned int sign : 1;
  } parts;
} double_cast;

int main() {
  double_cast d1;
  d1.f = 0.15625;
  printf("sign = %x\n",d1.parts.sign);
  printf("exponent = %x\n",d1.parts.exponent);
  printf("mantisa = %x\n",d1.parts.mantisa);
  return 0;
}
```

But how do I cast it as a double with the mantissa value being 52, exponent being 11, and sign being 1?

Answer (score 2):

Just extend the logic and define your union like this, using standard int 64 for portability:

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef union {
  double f;
  struct {
    uint64_t mantisa : 52;
    uint64_t exponent : 11;
    uint64_t sign : 1;
  } parts;
} double_cast;
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

BTW: the float mapping should be using the standard types as well instead of `int`:

```
typedef union {
  float f;
  struct {
    uint32_t mantisa : 23;
    uint32_t exponent : 8;
    uint32_t sign : 1;
  } parts;
} float_cast;
```

Comment: Thanks, what's the declaration for a long? What about for an 8 character value?

Comment: a `long` can be 8 bytes or 4 bytes or whatever, that's why `<stdint.h>` is there: to provide unified types with defined size.

Comment: That isn't very portable as the C standard doesn't restrict how bit-fields are laid out.

Comment: @2501 what isn't very portable?

Comment: @OregonState2016, your whole approach is non-portable.  You cannot rely on the unions to map the bitfields to the bits of the `float` / `double` in the way that you hope will happen.

Comment: @JohnBollinger is there a different approach you suggest?

Comment: @OregonState2016, yes, actually.  The `frexp()` family of functions is specifically intended for separating the sign+mantissa and exponent portions of floating-point numbers.  It's fairly straightforward to get from there to where you want to be.  Don't overlook the fact that a normalized IEEE-754 FP number has an extra implied 1 bit in its mantissa that you may need to account for.

Comment: @JohnBollinger While `frexp()` and `signbit()` are often an appropriate choice, they can be a little bit less than straightforward if one needs access to the exact *bit pattern* and the floating-point operands include NaNs and denormals,

Comment: True enough, @njuffa.  The only portable way to directly access the bit pattern of an object of real type is via a `char *` (+/- `signed` / `unsigned`, +/- qualifiers).  But there is no portable way to *interpret* the bit pattern accessed that way, since real number representation is not standardized by C.

Comment: @JohnBollinger If the C compiler supports Appendix F of the ISO-C99 spec (describing IEEE-754 bindings), the bit patterns are standardized. In practice, even without `__STD_IEC_559__` defined the risk of non-portability is tiny since there are exceedingly few platforms with a C compiler that use different floating-point formats (is MIL-STD-1750A still around?) Type-punning via union is sanctioned by ISO-C99, as far as I am aware (this has been covered elsewhere on SO, too lazy to search for the question right now)

Answer (score -1):

I think you should just use bit and shift operators to extracts the fields from double/float. You can make macro/function for that.

Comment: Bitwise operators are applicable only to integer types, not to `float`, `double`, or other real types.

Comment: Using a pointer to access an object of one type as if it were an object of a different type invokes undefined behavior.  There are a few exceptions, but the only one that could apply here would be accessing the real value via a `char *` or `unsigned char *`.  That could work, but it would be more complicated than simply shift / mask / done.