# How do I use ilogb with newLib?

Tags: gcc, arm, stm32, math.h, newlib

I am using a stm32 which uses [GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain](https://developer.arm.com/open-source/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm) which uses the newLib.

I added some the skeletons from [asn1c](http://lionet.info/asn1c/man-asn1c.html) and run into a linker problem when using floats. The Linker error says:

```
undefined reference to `ilogb'
```

It seems to me that newLib does not implement `ilogb` (see [man ilogb](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ilogb.3.html))

**How do I use `ilogb` with newLib or is there an alternative function I can call?**

Comment: it looks like problem in ASN.1, not in GCC. Try to read from here: https://sourceforge.net/p/asn1c/discussion/357921/thread/aa2f2ca4/

Comment: Hmm, your link looks more like primary problem in compiling the example. The author had forgotten to define the ` -DPDU=MyPDU`. I have no problem in compiling with the "normal" gcc on my host machine. The problem occurs when compiling with the mention arm-toolchain which uses the newLib.

Comment: I dont know anything about ASN.1, but simple call to ilogb(123.456) works fine in my project (I use latest gcc from arm.com and newlib-nano).

Comment: Oh, that sounds interesting. a simple call to `ilogb` does really not work for me. Would you please show your output of `arm-none-eabi-gcc --version`

Comment: I am try to build this https://yadi.sk/d/jFmO8ss-3YA3Gf code with  -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 and -mfloat-abi=soft. Everything works with

C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\7 2017-q4-major\bin>"arm-none-eabi-g++.exe" --version
arm-none-eabi-g++.exe (GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 7-2017-q4-major) 7.2.1 20170904 (release) [ARM/embedded-7-branch revision
 255204]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an alternative is to implement your own version of ilogb as it is done in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685181/how-to-get-the-sign-mantissa-and-exponent-of-a-floating-point-number?noredirect=1&lq=1).