# get exponent of float by assembly instruction from c on Intel Core i5/7

Tags: assembly, x86, floating-point, intel, itanium

I'm reading a book [bottom up](https://www.bottomupcs.com/types.xhtml) and it have instruction to get exponent of float on `c` compiled via `GCC`:

`asm ("getf.exp %0=%1" : "=r"(exp) : "f"(d));`

saying it works on Itanium. On my Core i7 GCC says `Error: no such instruction: 'getf.exp %rax=%st'`.

I've tried web search but could not find similar instruction for `Core iX` processors. Is there such?

Comment: I might start with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19608878/2189500).  There are all sorts of [reasons](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm) not to use inline asm.  This is #3.

Comment: No, x86 does not have such an instruction.  Use the `ilogb` function from `math.h` instead.  That said, the instructions of every architecture are different and assembly code written for one architecture generally does not work on any other.

Comment: @fuz: AVX512 has a similar instruction that gets the exponent *as a float*: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vgetexpps.  Floats will be in XMM registers so you can do integer bit-shifts and masking on them with SSE2 instructions instead of extracting the bit-pattern to integer.  But yeah, there's no reason to expect to find equivalents for IA-64 instructions on x86, except for the obvious stuff like `add`.

Comment: @PeterCordes OP says he has a Core i7 CPU and as far as I'm concerned, there are no Core i7 CPUs with AVX 512 on the market yet; only CPUs branded Xeon have AVX 512.   But yeah, you are technically correct.

Comment: @fuz: There are SKX i9 and i7 CPUs in the (expensive) HEDT series: https://www.anandtech.com/show/14463/intel-plans-to-phase-out-2017-skylake-x-processors.  But yeah, I wasn't suggesting the OP could use it on their CPU, just that x86 has it.  (In an extension that will be widespread in a few years, starting with IceLake for the mainstream.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah cool, that's new to me.