# What is the syntax I would use for the float on line 14?

Tags: arrays, c, count

```
Error:error: invalid operands to binary % (have ‘float’ and ‘int’)
   14 |         if(arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
      |            ~~~~~~ ^
      |               |
      |               float
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int size, i, j;
    float max, min, midpoint, sum = 0, avg, median, evenCount = 0, oddCount = 0, divisibleCount = 0;
    printf("Enter the size of the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    float arr[size];
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("Enter element %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &arr[i]);
        sum += arr[i];
        if(arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
            evenCount++;
        } else {
            oddCount++;
        }
        if(i == 0) {
            max = arr[i];
            min = arr[i];
        } else {
            if(arr[i] > max) {
                max = arr[i];
            }
            if(arr[i] < min) {
                min = arr[i];
            }
        }
    }
    midpoint = (max + min) / 2;
    int lessThanMidpoint = 0, greaterThanMidpoint = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(arr[i] == midpoint) {
            printf("Midpoint found at index %d using linear search.\n", i);
            break;
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(arr[i] < midpoint) {
            lessThanMidpoint++;
        } else if(arr[i] > midpoint) {
            greaterThanMidpoint++;
        }
        if((int)arr[i] % (int)min == 0) {
            divisibleCount++;
        }
    }
    avg = sum / size;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for(j = i+1; j < size; j++) {
            if(arr[i] > arr[j]) {
                float temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    if(size % 2 == 0) {
        median = (arr[size/2] + arr[(size/2)-1]) / 2;
    } else {
        median = arr[size/2];
    }
    printf("Array size: %d\n", size);
    printf("Maximum element: %0.2f\n", max);
    printf("Minimum element: %0.2f\n", min);
    printf("Midpoint: %0.2f\n", midpoint);
    printf("Number of elements less than midpoint: %d\n", lessThanMidpoint);
    printf("Number of elements greater than midpoint: %d\n", greaterThanMidpoint);
    printf("Sum of elements: %0.2f\n", sum);
    printf("Average of elements: %0.2f\n", avg);
    printf("Median of elements: %0.2f\n", median);
    printf("Number of even elements: %0.2f\n", evenCount);
    printf("Number of odd elements: %0.2f\n", oddCount);
    printf("Number of elements divisible by minimum value: %0.2f\n", divisibleCount);
    return 0;
}
```

Tried: changing the "%" in line 14 to %f, %lf, %0.2f and %.2lf

Results
main.c:14:20: error: ‘f’ undeclared (first use in this function)
14 |         if(arr[i] %f 2 == 0) {
|                    ^
main.c:14:20: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
main.c:14:21: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
14 |         if(arr[i] %f 2 == 0) {
|           ~         ^~
|                     )

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:14:20: error: invalid suffix "lf" on floating constant
   14 |         if(arr[i] %.2lf 2 == 0) {
      |                    ^~~~
main.c:14:24: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
   14 |         if(arr[i] %.2lf 2 == 0) {
      |           ~            ^~
      |                        )
```

Comment: The operator % is not defined for floating numbers in C. You could for example cast the left operand to the type int. Though it is unclear why the array is declared with the type specifier float instead of int.

Comment: The suffix is L by the way.

Comment: `if(fmodf(arr[i], 2.f) == 0.f)` would be syntactically correct but I doubt it'll do what you want.

Comment: Is 1.999999 even or odd?

Comment: @Corvus For an optimist the number is even. For a pessimist the number is odd.

Comment: `fmodf` can replace `%` for floats [or `remainder`]. But, you may want to extract the mantissa see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685181/how-to-get-the-sign-mantissa-and-exponent-of-a-floating-point-number Then, you could do (e.g.) `mantissa & 1` to see even/odd. But, it's all a bit dicey because the least significant bit of a float can vary. I'd consider converting to a fixed point number of some sort.

Comment: Also, using `float` (vs. `int`) for _counters_ will just complicate things. (i.e.) you want: `int evenCount = 0, oddCount = 0;` with adjustments to the corresponding `printf` calls.

Comment: You need to post the actual problem statement. I doubt that you are supposed to have an array of `float`.

Answer (score 2):

> **Remainder**
>
> The binary operator % yields the remainder of the division
> of the first operand by the second (after usual arithmetic
> conversions).
>
> The sign of the remainder is defined in such a way that if the
> quotient `a/b` is representable in the result type, then `(a/b)*b + a%b == a`.
>
> If the second operand is zero, the behavior is undefined.
>
> If the quotient `a/b` is not representable in the result type, the
> behavior of both `a/b` and `a%b` is undefined (that means `INT_MIN%-1` is
> undefined on 2's complement systems)
>
> **Note:
> the remainder operator does not work on floating-point types,
> the library function `fmod()` provides that functionality.**
> — cppreference.com