# Storing rgb color in a single float value between 0 and 1 without information loss

Tags: floating-point, rgb, bit-shift

I have three integer values (rgb) between 0 and 255. I want to store this information in a single float value between 0 and 1 without information loss.

My approach was to bitshift the values into a new integer meaning:

```
int rgb = (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b;
```

and then divide the result by the 2^24 to get it between 0 and 1.

This works fine so far because you can recover each color value.

The problem i have is that i need each color value to be evenly weighted in the solution.

The resulting float value is changing a lot when the red part is being modified, whereas the changes are small when tweaking the blue part.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: You could redistribute the bits of each color component individually so that the relative "weights" aren't quite so extremely different. But fundamentally you are trying to take a three-dimensional array of points and label them sequentially. There will be "jumps" in the sequence _somewhere._

Comment: If you interleaved the bytes from rgb (one bit from red, one bit from green, one bit from blue, ...) you would get closer to your desired behaviour. Or if you transform to HSV, instead of rgb, equal changes to red green an blue would change the float very little, but unequal changes would change the hue and therefore change the float a lot.

Comment: When you say "a single float value," does that mean single-precision IEEE-754, or are you allowed to use double precision?

Comment: @DavidK i mean "one 32bit float value"

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

```
int lightness = r + g + b;
int exp1 = lightness / 8;
int man1 = lightness % 8;
```

This sets `lightness` to a value in the range 0..765,
`exp1` to a value in the range 0..95, 
and `man1` to a value in the range 0..7.

```
int mantissa_bits = (1 << 23) + (man1 << 20) + (r << 8) + g;
```

This sets `mantissa` to a non-negative integer less than 2^24,
but not less than 2^23.

```
float multiplier = pow(2, exp1 - 119);
```

This sets `multiplier` to a power of 2 no less than 2^-119
and no greater than 2^-24.

```
float rgb_encoding = mantissa * multiplier;
```

This sets `rgb_encoding` to a number less than 2^24 * 2^-24 = 1, but no less than 2^23 * 2^-119 = 2^-96.
The leading bit of `mantissa_bits`, which is always `1 << 23`,
becomes the implicit most significant bit of the floating-point value
(which is not actually stored in the bits of `rgb_encoding`)
while the next 23 bits of `mantissa_bits` become the actual stored
mantissa of `rgb_encoding` with no loss of information.

Now if you increase or decrease any of the values of `r`, `g`, or `b`
by 1, you change the value of `rgb_encoding` by at least 6.6%.
The change in `rgb_encoding` is very slightly larger if you change `r`
than if you change `b`.
For example, if `r` = 127, `g` = 15, `b` = 95, then
`mantissa_bits` = 13664015 (0x00d07f0f hexadecimal).
Increasing `b` by 1 changes `mantissa_bits` to 14712591
(an increase of 1048576),
but increasing `r` by 1 changes `mantissa_bits` to 14712847
(an increase of 1048832).

To decode the RGB data from `rgb_encoding`, 
get its exponent using `double frexp(double value, int *exp)`
(as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14954088/how-do-i-handle-byte-order-differences-when-reading-writing-floating-point-types/14955046#14955046)),
use the value of `exp` to multiply `rgb_encoding` by a power of 2 that
produces an integer value between 2^23 and 2^24,
cast it to an `int`, extract bits 20 through 22 and add these to
`8 * (exp + 119)`.
This gives the value of `r + g + b`.
Get the values of `r` and `g` from the least significant 16 bits of the 
integer, and subtract `r + g` from `r + g + b` to get `b`.

The trick here is that we've stored just 23 bits of information in the
mantissa of `rgb_encoding`, but almost 7 bits of information in
the 8-bit exponent of `rgb_encoding`.
As a result, the encoded value represents the lightness of the original
RGB color in a non-linear way, 
and darker colors map to *very* small values of `rgb_encoding`, although still in the range of normal positive `float` values.
We've made use of those 30 bits by storing the 
completely symmetric information of `r + g + b`
in the 10 bits that have the greatest impact on the encoded value,
and the asymmetric information of `r` and `g` in the 16 bits that have the
least impact on the encoded value. We've also left 4 bits in the middle
at constant zeros in order to amplify the significance of the
symmetric information over the asymmetric information.