# Should I use numpy.float64 instead of Python float when also using numpy.array

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, precision

I have not encountered any problems thus far, so this is a question purely out of curiosity.

In Python I usually define floats and arrays of floats like this:

```
import numpy as np

s = 1.0
v = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
```

In the case above `s` is a `float`, but the elements of `v` are of type `numpy.float64`.

To be more consistent I could, for example, do this instead:

```
import numpy as np

s = np.float64(1.0)
v = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
```

Are there cases, from an accuracy/precision point of view, where it is recommended to use the "consistent" approach? What kind of errors, if any, can I expect in the "inconsistent" approach?

Comment: I'd use `s=np.array(1.0, dtype=...)` if I wanted a scalar of a special dtype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python (at least [CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.2/Include/floatobject.h#L15-L18)) uses doubles for it's `float` type internally - and doubles are 64bit floats (maybe not always but I haven't found a platform + compiler where doubles weren't 64bit floats).

So you shouldn't expect any kind of problems no matter if you keep them as `float` or `np.float64`.

However if you use Pythons `float` and NumPys `np.float32` you could expect differences as the `float` has more precision (64 bits) than a `np.float32` (32 bits).

Comment: The assumption that C doubles have 8 bytes is still hard-wired into various places in the CPython source, so if CPython were ever to meet a platform where the double wasn't 64 bits, it would probably break quite badly. (And yes, I'm assuming that bytes have 8 bits, but if CPython ever met a platform where bytes didn't have 8 bits, it would break even badlier.) So IOW, your assumption that doubles are 64-bit floats is a fairly safe one. :-)

Comment: Here's an example of one such place where 8-byte doubles are assumed, in the marshal module: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.2/Python/marshal.c#L362-L369

Comment: @MarkDickinson That's good to know. I only did a superficial search and I assumed there *might* be differences when I found a question where the author wanted to ["Ensure C++ doubles are 64 bits"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752309/ensuring-c-doubles-are-64-bits).