# Why does NumPy return a different type for arrays and scalars?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, type-conversion, numpy-ndarray

I have some whole numbers stored in `np.float64` arrays and scalars, which I want to convert to native Python `int`.

This is my attempt:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=np.float64)
b = np.float64(4)

def float_to_int(x):
    x_object = x.astype(object)
    return np.floor(x_object)

# Array inputs are converted to int
print(type(float_to_int(a)[0]))
# >> <class 'int'>

# Scalar inputs are left as np.float64
print(type(float_to_int(b)))
# >> <class 'numpy.float64'>
```

There are 3 things I don't understand here:

1. Why is the type casting different for scalars and arrays?
2. Why did `np.floor()` do type casting at all (for array inputs)?
3. How can I reliably cast `np.float64` to `int` for scalars and arrays?

Comment: Be careful with the `astype(object)`.  You have two unknowns.  1) how the array elements are converted to the python objects,  2) how the numpy function is applied to an object dtype array.  Typically it's something like `[i.foo() for i in objarray]`.  You/I don't know what that `foo` method is.  I can guess in some obvious cases,or from errors. But here I'm not sure what the 'floor' method is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe since Numpy and python data types are related but inherently different, you would have to explicitly convert it to python data type.

One way to do it would be:

```
a = a.astype(np.int64).tolist()
b = int(b)
```

or alternatively

```
a = a.astype(np.int64).astype(object)
b = b.astype(np.int64).astype(object)
```

When you convert numpy array to [object](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.object_) data type, it internally stores it as python objects. The object data type is flexible and inferred during conversion.

Comment: All of the `astype(int)` calls return `np.int32`. Therefore, this fails for any values that cannot be represented as 32-bit integers. `np.float64` can represent integers up to roughly `2**53`. So I think if you replace `astype(int)` with `astype(np.int64)`, then I think this could be going in the right direction.

Comment: `astype(int)` is platform specific https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html. For most platforms(64 bit), it translates to np.int64. If you specifically want it to be int64, like you said you could use astype(np.int64)

Comment: I followed the link, but couldn't find where it says `astype(int)` is platform-specific. Could you point me to the section? I don't specifically want `np.int64`, but I would like a solution that will not break on some platforms (including all 4 that I have access to).

Comment: Okay, then your current answer may work on some platforms, but it doesn't work on any of mine. So, I won't accept this answer in its current state.

Comment: ```There are 5 basic numerical types representing booleans (bool), integers (int), unsigned integers (uint) floating point (float) and complex. Those with numbers in their name indicate the bitsize of the type (i.e. how many bits are needed to represent a single value in memory). Some types, such as int and intp, have differing bitsizes, dependent on the platforms (e.g. 32-bit vs. 64-bit machines). This should be taken into account when interfacing with low-level code (such as C or Fortran) where the raw memory is addressed.```

Sure, I will change to use int64

Comment: I am not sure about your concern here though. If you are on a 32 bit machine, you can't hold 64 bit numbers anyway, so you wont get any more precise than using only `int`

Comment: All of the systems I am testing on are 64-bit and support `np.int64`. The details of why `astype(int)` converts to `np.int32` and not `np.int64` are unclear to me. The documentation you quoted above didn't make sense to me because `int` has arbitrary precision in Python, meaning the bit-width may be arbitrarily large, independent of the CPU architecture.

Comment: I think you may have answered part (3) of my question, but I am still working through it now.

Comment: Could you try this  answer to see which numpy you have? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33553549/do-i-have-numpy-32-bit-or-64-bit

Comment: Yes: `platform.architecture()` returns `('64bit', 'WindowsPE')` on the two systems I have easiest access to.

Comment: Not sure either in that case. May be you can post a different question and someone might have be able to help out.

Comment: From numerous SO, I've learned to be cautious about how numpy functions (and operators) are applied to object dtype arrays.  It seems to be some sort of list comprehension with a per element method.  But that method is not documented.  So math on object dtype arrays is hit-of-miss.

Answer (score 1):

For dealing with the numpy 'scalar', a couple of possibly useful tools are `item`, and `math` module.

```
In [167]: import math
```

Making a scalar by extracting an element of a float array (I don't recommend ever using `np.float64()` directly):

```
In [168]: b = np.array([1.23,3.3])[0]
In [169]: type(b)
Out[169]: numpy.float64
```

Extracting that value as native python

```
In [170]: c = b.item()
In [171]: c
Out[171]: 1.23
In [172]: type(c)
Out[172]: float
```

`b.tolist()` and `float(b)` also work.

`math` has a lot of the same functions like numpy, but is designed to work with single python values - and faster for that purpose.

```
In [174]: math.floor(c)
Out[174]: 1
In [175]: math.floor(b)
Out[175]: 1
```

In contrast to `np.floor` which returns `np` numbers, even when given a python number.  Numpy functions are like the proverbial hammer, 'everything  is a nail/numpy array'.

```
In [176]: np.floor(b)
Out[176]: 1.0
In [177]: type(_)
Out[177]: numpy.float64
In [178]: np.floor(c)
Out[178]: 1.0
In [179]: type(_)
Out[179]: numpy.float64
```

Using this would require a test to distinguish the scalar, such as checking `b.ndim` is 0.

I commented about casting to `object` dtype.  Note that this casting is different arrays and array-scalars:

```
In [191]: np.array([1.23]).astype(object)
Out[191]: array([1.23], dtype=object)
In [192]: b.astype(object)
Out[192]: 1.23
```

One is an array (even `np.array(1.23)` casts this way); the other a python, like `item()`.  So a following `np.floor` call will have to very different classes to work on.

The action of `numpy` functions on object dtype arrays is a bit kludgey.  Usually it iterates in list comprehension fashion, applying some method to each element.  For operators it apparently uses methods like `.__add__`.  For `np.sin` (and like), errors suggest it's trying to do `[i.sin() for i in arr]`.

We can only guess as to what it's trying to do with `np.float`.  Maybe it is doing `[math.floor(i) for i in arr]`.

Comment: Could you comment on why you don't recommend ever using `np.float64` directly? I did wonder about that, but just found this SO answer that seems to imply there should be no problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45569134/4220282

Comment: It isn't so much that it's wrong or creates a problem, but why would you create a `np.float64(1.23)` as opposed to using the simple Python float `1.23`.  Yes, we do need to understand what `arr[0]` produces, but do we need to create it explicitly?  These `numpy scalars` are a bit of odd-duck.  `np.array([1.23])` is a 1d array; `np.array(1.23)` is a 0d with the same data.  `np.float64(1.23)` is practically the same, except it's immutable.

Comment: I thought there might be an advantage to the "practically the same" you mention. For example, if I write methods that do things like `.astype(...)`, then passing a `float` into that method will cause an error, whereas `np.float64` will work. But I must admit, the different behaviors of `np.array([1.23])`, `np.array(1.23)` and `np.float64(1.23)` are incredibly confusing to me.

Comment: numpy functions routinely do a `x=np.asarray(x)` to their arguments.

Answer (score 0):

1. In NumPy, scalars and arrays are treated differently due to their distinct characteristics and usage scenarios. Scalars, which represent single values, are regarded as zero-dimensional arrays in NumPy, while arrays have a higher rank or dimensionality. This differentiation influences the behavior of type-casting operations.

Look at the documentation for more idea:

- NumPy Scalars: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html
- NumPy Arrays: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.html
- Array Casting: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#array-casting

2. For the array input `a`, `float_to_int(a)` returns an array with the elements rounded down to the nearest integer. When you access the first element using `[0]`, it returns a Python `int` because you are explicitly accessing the element, and Python automatically converts the data type to `int`.

For the scalar input `b`, `float_to_int(b)` returns a scalar of type `np.float64` because it is consistent with the original data type.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but I get `<class 'numpy.int32'>` in both cases, not `int`.

Comment: you could try the `astype(np.int32).item()` method, sometimes this gives the desired output

Comment: That seems to give `<class 'numpy.float64'>` in  both cases.

Comment: Yup, i ran into that issue, too. Changed the approach: used astype(int). This solved it. See if this works for you too.

Comment: Your updated answer has fixed the scalar case, but broken the array case (which now only returns element `[0]`).

Comment: Now you have changed it back to the version where an array returns `<class 'numpy.int32'>`, not `int`.

Comment: yup, i was trying something new. i am new to this and still getting the hang of this. I couldn't  get the 3rd questions answered, but the first 2 are there.  Hope that helps

Comment: Part (2) of your answer describes exactly the opposite behavior to what I observe. Your answer says I should expect `np.float64`, but I see `int`.

Comment: Part (1) of your answer tells me to read the documentation, which I have already tried to do (but I find quite overwhelming). If you could help me to focus on a particular section of the documentation, then that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: for part (1) I refered to this documentation https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

for part (2) i got this explanation when i asked around on my Slack workspace:
For the array input a, float_to_int(a) returns an array with the elements rounded down to the nearest integer. When you access the first element using [0], it returns a Python int because you are explicitly accessing the element, and Python automatically converts the data type to int.