# Necessary C compiler flags to check MacOS (old and new) for IEEE-754 compliance

Tags: c, macos, c-preprocessor, ieee-754

It seems as if `__STDC_IEC_559__` is insufficient to test for IEEE-754 compliance within the Apple ecosystem whcih leads to my question:

Which MacOS does support IEEE-754 full or at least the part with the binary32 and binary64 format and how to test for it with one or more C preprocessor macros?

Comment: Maybe the second part of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/753018/4944425 could be of some help.

Comment: @Bob__ Checking those constants needs to include `float.h` which I want to avoid, although not at all costs.

Comment: Apple’s developer tools with macOS, OS X, and Mac OS use IEEE-754 basic 32-bit and 64-bit binary floating-point formats but do not fully comply with IEEE-754. (Technically the first sentence of your question is incorrect: `__STDC_IEC_559__` is sufficient to test for compliance; it correctly indicates the implementation does not comply.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It seems as if __STDC_IEC_559_ is insufficient to test for IEEE-754 compliance within the Apple ecosystem.

Yes and no.  For one thing, it depends in part on your compiler, not just OS.  For another, you need to be careful how you interpret the compiler's use of that macro.

As a preliminary matter, the `__STDC_IEC_559__` macro (note: *two* trailing underscores) was introduced in C99.  There are still compilers out there that do not conform to C99, at least by default.  For it to make any sense to test `__STD_IEC_559__` at all, then, you should first check whether the compiler claims to conform to C99 or later:

```
#if __STDC__ && __STDC_VERSION__ >= 19901L
// __STDC_IEC_559__ may tell us something ...
#endif
```

Supposing that you're working with a conforming implementation, you next need to appreciate that if an implementation defines `__STDC_IEC_559__` to 1, it is asserting that it conforms to *all* the specifications in Annex F (C11) or Annex G (C99) of the standard, which cover not only floating-point data formats but also a fairly wide variety of specifications for operators and functions, including error bounds.  The `__STDC_IEC_559__` *not* being defined does not say anything about which part(s) are unsupported.  In practice, almost everyone uses ISO 60559 data formats these days, but full ISO 60559 conformance is relatively rare.

> Which MacOS does support IEEE-754 full or at least the part with the binary32 and binary64 format and how to test for it with one or more C preprocessor macros?

To the best of my knowledge, all versions of MacOS / OS X running on Intel chips support binary32 and binary64 as native floating-point formats.  All the common compilers for those platforms map those native types to C `float` and `double`.  There is no reliable, standard way to get the C preprocessor test that, however, because no standard macros provide that information, and actual testing would require floating-point math, which the preprocessor does not perform.

The closest you can come to testing the data formats via the preprocessor is to include `float.h` and examine the macros that define the characteristics of types `float` and `double`.  But even if these characteristics exactly match those of binary32 / binary64, that does not prove that the actual representations in memory take those forms.  If you specifically care about the representation, then you'll need an external test program.

Comment: Feared that, but thought was worth a question anyways. Will just check for the things I actually need to know (am down to just `*_MAX_EXP` and `FLT_RADIX`) and write arch./mem.-layout independent code for the rest. Much slower but also much less hassle. Thanks!

Comment: @deamentiaemundi: One possible DeathStation 9000 gotcha would be float endian not matching integer endian, so type-punning for `float` to `uint32_t` would have the sign bit as `u32 & 0x80`.  AFAIK, there's no standard `__FLT_ENDIAN__` macro.  But all real compilers go far beyond being standards compliant and make real efforts to actually be useful.  (quality of implementation).  x86 has little-endian integers and floats, and all the major x86 compilers (gcc/clang/ICC/MSVC) are all sane.  (PowerPC has big-endian int and float, I think, if you care about Macs that old.)

Comment: @PeterCordes "if you care about Macs that old" Well, I do, of course I do! The minimum I need is just a M68K + MMU + FPU (e.g.: M68040 to get it all in one) with a slice of RAM aside.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi: Oh, I only saw the macos tag, missed the (old and new) in the title.  The abstract of https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/63685 confirms that 68040 hardware uses the IEEE 754 FP formats (and thus so do older m68k with 68882 / 68881, because we know they're compatible), and the FPU is conformant as expected.  But beware of float endian issues in binary files if you care about moving data between systems.